# Case insensitive query params in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, uri

I've a query string in the browser like this `https://application.com/loader/?orderNumber=313Q&tracerId=PLM5689`.

I wanna keep the keys in the query case-insensitive i.e if the `ORDERNUMBER=313Q` and `TrAcErid=PLM5689`

or

`ordernumber=313Q` and `tracerid=PLM5689`

would still work the same way.

So far I'm using a workaround by iterating over the `params.keys` and basically checking if it matches my parameters.

```
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {

      params.keys.forEach(key => {
        if (key.toLowerCase() === 'ordernumber') {
          this.ordernumber= params.get(key);
        }
        if (key.toLowerCase() === 'tracerid') {
          this.tracerid= params.get(key);
        }
      });
 });
```

Is there a better to handle this or some sort of best practice to work with query strings. I expect that I will be needing this a lot in my application.

While this works, it feels like a hacky way to do it.
I came across few posts which suggested that the parameters in query string are case-sensitive, but I didn't quiet seem to understand it.

RFC 3986 : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.3

and this https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90339/why-are-urls-case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

After perusing the internet and not finding a satisfactory solution, I wrote my own re-usable class that wraps the built-in `Params` object and provides case-insensitive access to query string parameters.

You can use it in your component like:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CaseInsensitiveParamMap } from '../case-insensitive-param-map';

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  // subscribe to query params changes:
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.snapshot.paramMap
    .subscribe((params) => this.handleQueryParamsChanged(new CaseInsensitiveParamMap(params)));

  // or use the params from the route snapshot:
  const paramMap = new CaseInsensitiveParamMap(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams);
  const returnUrl = paramMap.get('returnUrl');
}

private handleQueryParamsChanged(paramMap: CaseInsensitiveParamMap): void {
  const returnUrl = paramMap.get('returnUrl');
  // Returns the value of the first query param named 'returnUrl' case-insensitively
  // See the test suite below for more examples
}
```

Note that I also added a `getNumber` helper method that makes it much easier to parse numeric query params. It returns `null` if the value is not a number or is not present.

Here is the class:

`case-insensitive-param-map.ts`

```
import { ParamMap, Params } from '@angular/router';

export class CaseInsensitiveParamMap implements ParamMap {
  private params: Params;

  constructor(params: Params) {
    this.params = params || {};
  }

  has(name: string): boolean {
    return Object.keys(this.params).some((key) => key.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase());
  }

  private getKeysCaseInsensitively(name: string): string[] {
    return Object.keys(this.params).filter((key) => key.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase());
  }

  get(name: string): string | null {
    if (this.has(name)) {
      const keys = this.getKeysCaseInsensitively(name);
      const v = this.params[keys[0]];
      return Array.isArray(v) ? v[0] : v;
    }

    return null;
  }

  getNumber(name: string): number | null {
    const v = this.get(name);
    return !v || isNaN(Number(v)) ? null : Number(v);
  }

  getAll(name: string): string[] {
    if (this.has(name)) {
      const result: string[] = [];
      this.getKeysCaseInsensitively(name).forEach((key) => {
        const v = this.params[key];
        result.push(...(Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]));
      });
      return result;
    }

    return [];
  }

  get keys(): string[] {
    return Object.keys(this.params);
  }
}
```

Here is the tests that outline the behavior and serve as documentation:

`case-insensitive-param-map.spec.ts`

```
import { Params } from '@angular/router';
import { CaseInsensitiveParamMap } from './case-insensitive-param-map';

describe('CaseInsensitiveParamMap', () => {
  it('should return whether a case-insensitive parameter is present', () => {
    const params: Params = { single: 's', multiple: ['m1', 'm2'] };
    const map: CaseInsensitiveParamMap = new CaseInsensitiveParamMap(params);
    expect(map.has('single')).toEqual(true);
    expect(map.has('SINGLE')).toEqual(true);
    expect(map.has('multiple')).toEqual(true);
    expect(map.has('MULTIPLE')).toEqual(true);
    expect(map.has('not here')).toEqual(false);
  });

  it('should return the keys of the parameters', () => {
    const params: Params = { single: 's', multiple: ['m1', 'm2'] };
    const map: CaseInsensitiveParamMap = new CaseInsensitiveParamMap(params);
    expect(map.keys).toEqual(['single', 'multiple']);
  });

  it('should support single valued parameters', () => {
    const params: Params = { single: 's', multiple: ['m1', 'm2'] };
    const map: CaseInsensitiveParamMap = new CaseInsensitiveParamMap(params);
    expect(map.get('single')).toEqual('s');
    expect(map.get('multiple')).toEqual('m1');
  });

  it('should get numeric query string values as numbers', () => {
    const params: Params = { single: '1', multiple: ['2', '3'], nonnumeric: 'foo', empty: '', zero: '0', nullProp: null, undefinedProp: undefined };
    const map: CaseInsensitiveParamMap = new CaseInsensitiveParamMap(params);
    expect(map.getNumber('single')).toEqual(1);
    expect(map.getNumber('multiple')).toEqual(2);
    expect(map.getNumber('zero')).toEqual(0);
    expect(map.getNumber('nullProp')).toEqual(null);
    expect(map.getNumber('undefinedProp')).toEqual(null);
    expect(map.getNumber('nonnumeric')).toEqual(null);
    expect(map.getNumber('not here')).toEqual(null);
    expect(map.getNumber('empty')).toEqual(null);
  });

  it('should support case-insensitive single valued parameters', () => {
    const params: Params = { SINGLE: 'S', MULTIPLE: ['M1', 'M2'] };
    const map: CaseInsensitiveParamMap = new CaseInsensitiveParamMap(params);
    expect(map.get('single')).toEqual('S');
    expect(map.get('SINGLE')).toEqual('S');
    expect(map.get('Single')).toEqual('S');
    expect(map.get('multiple')).toEqual('M1');
    expect(map.get('MULTIPLE')).toEqual('M1');
    expect(map.get('Multiple')).toEqual('M1');
  });

  it('should support multiple valued parameters', () => {
    const params: Params = { single: 's', multiple: ['m1', 'm2'] };
    const map: CaseInsensitiveParamMap = new CaseInsensitiveParamMap(params);
    expect(map.getAll('single')).toEqual(['s']);
    expect(map.getAll('multiple')).toEqual(['m1', 'm2']);
  });

  it('should support case-insensitive multiple valued parameters', () => {
    const params: Params = { SINGLE: 'S', MULTIPLE: ['M1', 'M2'], multiple: ['M3'] };
    const map: CaseInsensitiveParamMap = new CaseInsensitiveParamMap(params);
    expect(map.getAll('single')).toEqual(['S']);
    expect(map.getAll('multiple')).toEqual(['M1', 'M2', 'M3']);
  });

  it('should return null when a single valued element is absent', () => {
    expect(new CaseInsensitiveParamMap({}).get('not here')).toEqual(null);
  });

  it('should return [] when a multiple valued element is absent', () => {
    expect(new CaseInsensitiveParamMap({}).getAll('not here')).toEqual([]);
  });
});
```